# Iterating over an array and changing items in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

How can I iterate over an array in typescript, while being able to modify the iterator if I need to? I have the following typescript logic in my program:

```
for let list_item of list
    if list_item matches condition:
        modify list_item
```

However this does not work, because I guess typescript does not return a mutable iterator? How can I make this happen? This could be done by enumerating over the array, e.g. `for(let list_item, index of list) { ... }`, but I don't know if this exists.

Here is an example of the issue i'm having: goo.gl/5eDNsD

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it that way. `list_item` is not some kind of pointer to the value in the array, via which you can modify the array. `list_item` is just a plain old value, and modifying it will accomplish nothing. If you want to modify the array, you have to modify the array using `list[idx]`. That of course means you won't be able to use the `for...of` loop as is, since it doesn't give you the index.

The construct `for(let list_item, index of list) { ... }` you are looking for is

```
for (let [idx, list_item] of list.entries()) { 
  if list_item matches condition:
    modify list[idx]
}
```

By the way, this has nothing in particular to do with TypeScript.

Comment: When I use `entries()`, I get an array iterator of length zero, any ideas what's up?

Comment: Right, it returns an iterator. Then you have to do something to grab the iterated values, such as `for...of`, or `[...iterator]`, or `Array.from(iterator)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by modify the iterator? As far as  can tell you want to iterate over the elements and modify the elements if they satisfy a particular condition. If that is the case you can use `map`

```
list = list.map(list_item => {
    if list_item matches condition
        modify list_item and return
    }
return list_item
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like this one: https://github.com/labs42io/itiriri#map

And then simply:

```
import {query} from 'itiriri';
query([1, 2, 3]).map(elem => elem * 10).toArray(); // returns [10, 20, 30]
```